# Change color of highlighted textbox when using the jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I just tried out the jQuery Validation Plugin and when I click in a textbox it gets highlighted with a brownish/beige color, how can I change this to another color?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the outline is applied by the plugin. The light yellow color on focused inputs is part of Chrome's default stylesheet. If you want to remove the outline, use this CSS rule:

```
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

The syntax for this is the same as that for the `border` property. However, you should still try to give focused elements some sort of highlighting, for accessibility.

Comment: The validation plugin itself applies no css-rules or provides classes.

Comment: thanks, I'm not an avid user of chrome so I never thought about it.